# Error (Status of 500) and X-Frame-Options with google apps script redirect function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am currently trying to build a web app with google apps script, and I have implemented a login function.
The login happens as it should, but I then try to redirect the user to the dashboard of my web app. The current code for the dashboard is the basic code for a new HTML file within apps script with a h1 title, so there are no issues with it.

In my login.html file, this is how it should redirect the user to the dashboard page:

```
function onLoginSuccess(sessionId) {
      if (sessionId) {
        console.log('Success')
        console.log(sessionId)
        window.location.href = "dashboard?sessionId=" + sessionId;
        console.log('Success')
      } else {
        alert("Invalid email or password. Please try again.");
      }
    }
```

I have tried an url with `"dashboard.html?sessionId=" +sessionId` and I get the following error in the F12 console: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`
I then tried an url without the html `"dashboard?sessionId=" +sessionId` and I now get the following error: `Refused to display 'https://developers.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`
I then tried adding `.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);` with my return HtmlService line, but I still get the error.

With both URLs, both success and the session ID get called into the console.

Is there a way to fix the issue? Maybe another way to redirect the user, or just a way to fix the error?

Comment: I seem to have managed to make it work using the full application URL, but it would still be great to be able to just use the url part that needs to be added to redirect.